# FTDI driver MacBook Pro running Ventura 13.4 - for Brother Knitting Machine

Tags: driver

Is there any way I can identify the driver that is supposed to be allowing communication between my laptop and this external appliance to see whether in fact anything is working at all? I keep trying to send information to the knitting machine from my laptop and the knitting machine just goes unresponsive.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the model of knitting machine you're trying to connect to? I'm _assuming_ you've checked the Brother site for driver updates, and I'm _assuming_ you're connecting through USB. Also _assuming_ the vintage of the MBP as being relative recent. Are you connecting through USB-C or USB-A?